# Java: Displaying Array Created From Method In Another Class

Tags: java, arrays, swing, constructor, jtextarea

Trying to get my button attached to an actionListener to populate my JTextArea with a new randomly generated array of a user entered number of items, generated from another class/method. I can get it partially functioning, but not fully.

I can get this to work by having the button create an entirely new GUI window, but that's not what I want, I just want to append the JTextArea with the newly generated array. As-is, the JTextArea displays the class infor and hex code of the array and nothing else.

Function: The user enters an integer into a box which tells the method how many items to populate the array with, clicks a button, and a randomly generated array appears after the JTextArea is cleared.

I'm guessing (hoping) this is a fairly simple issue. I have put all applicable (I think) code from the two .java files.

Automobile.java:

```
//toString method override for formatting
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format
        ("   %d\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%d\t%1.1fL", invID, make, model, doors, engineSize);
}// end method toString


//This method randomizes the array
public static Automobile[] makeRandom(int m) {
    Automobile[] auto = new Automobile[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < auto.length; i++) {
        auto[i] = new Automobile();
        auto[i].make = carMakes.get(randomGen.nextInt(carMakes.size()));
        auto[i].model = carModels.get(randomGen.nextInt(carModels.size()));
        auto[i].doors = randomGen.nextInt(6);
            if(auto[i].doors == 0 || auto[i].doors == 1)
                auto[i].doors = 2;
        auto[i].engineSize = randomGen.nextDouble() * 6.0;
            if(auto[i].engineSize <= 1.49)
                auto[i].engineSize = 1.5;
    } // end for method to instantiate     
    return auto;
} // end method makeRandom

//Main method for creating the GUI with default number of array entries
public static void main(String args[]) {

Automobile[] x = makeRandom(20);
GUI frame = new GUI(x);
frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

GUI.java

```
//Creates the GUI    
public GUI(Automobile[] ia) {
    this.autoArray = ia;
    initComponents();

    for (Automobile m : autoArray) {
        mainTextArea.append(m.toString()+"\n");

    }

    Arrays.sort(autoArray);
    mainTextArea.append("\n\n---- Sorted By Make -----\n");
    for (Automobile m : autoArray) {
        mainTextArea.append(m.toString() + "\n");
    }
    mainTextArea.append("\n\n---- Sorted By Model -----\n");
    Automobile.sortBy = Automobile.SORTBY.MODEL;
    Arrays.sort(autoArray);
    for (Automobile m : autoArray) {
        mainTextArea.append(m.toString() + "\n");
    }
    mainTextArea.append("\n\n---- Sorted By Doors -----\n");
    Automobile.sortBy = Automobile.SORTBY.DOORS;
    Arrays.sort(autoArray);
    for (Automobile m : autoArray) {
        mainTextArea.append(m.toString() + "\n");
    }
    mainTextArea.append("\n\n---- Sorted By Engine Size -----\n");
    Automobile.sortBy = Automobile.SORTBY.ENGINESIZE;
    Arrays.sort(autoArray);
    for (Automobile m : autoArray) {
        mainTextArea.append(m.toString() + "\n");
    }
}//End GUI constructor

//Method for the button click action
private void randomizeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

   int number = Integer.parseInt(numCarsTextField.getText());
   mainTextArea.setText(null);
   Automobile[] x = makeRandom(number);
   mainTextArea.append(x.toString());  
   }
```

Would really appreciate some guidance.

Thanks!

Adding some code that I'm trying, suggested by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, this is the new method, but I'm not even sure what to do with it, I would REALLY appreciate some more in-depth help here:

```
public void appendAutos(Automobile[] cars){

    this.autoArray = cars;
    initComponents();

    for (Automobile m : autoArray) {
        mainTextArea.append(m.toString()+"\n");

    }

    Arrays.sort(autoArray);
    mainTextArea.append("\n\n---- Sorted By Make -----\n");
    for (Automobile m : autoArray) {
        mainTextArea.append(m.toString() + "\n");
    }
    mainTextArea.append("\n\n---- Sorted By Model -----\n");
    Automobile.sortBy = Automobile.SORTBY.MODEL;
    Arrays.sort(autoArray);
    for (Automobile m : autoArray) {
        mainTextArea.append(m.toString() + "\n");
    }
    mainTextArea.append("\n\n---- Sorted By Doors -----\n");
    Automobile.sortBy = Automobile.SORTBY.DOORS;
    Arrays.sort(autoArray);
    for (Automobile m : autoArray) {
        mainTextArea.append(m.toString() + "\n");
    }
    mainTextArea.append("\n\n---- Sorted By Engine Size -----\n");
    Automobile.sortBy = Automobile.SORTBY.ENGINESIZE;
    Arrays.sort(autoArray);
    for (Automobile m : autoArray) {
        mainTextArea.append(m.toString() + "\n");
    }
}    

    private void randomizeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent   evt) {                                                

   int number = Integer.parseInt(numCarsTextField.getText());
   mainTextArea.setText(null);
   appendAutos(Automobile[]);
```

I'm not sure what the return type is supposed to be or how to pass the user entered number into method, since it was suggested that the method accept an array type.

Comment: Does it make sense to call `initComponents()` from within your `appendAutos(...)` method? Before copying code, think about what each line of code does.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Give GUI a `setAutos(Automobile[] cars)` or `appendAutos(...)` method, and call your auto display code that you currently do in the constructor in this method. Then call the method from within your actionPerformed method.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate a little bit more, perhaps with some code? I think I follow you, but I'm trying to put everything together. Thanks!

Comment: @bnr32jason: try it first. You've already got the code, that you wrote, so you should understand it.

Comment: But how do I pass the user-entered integer into the method setAutos that you have suggested? I think what I'm failing to understand is why I'm pulling the code from the constructor and putting it into a new method, seems I'm doing the same thing, just in a different way.

Comment: @bnr32jason: what's confusing? You get the int in the actionPerformed, you call your factory method to get your auto array, you pass the array into the `setAutos(...)` method.

Comment: I'm trying, but the more I change around, the worse it gets. I'm not sure why I'm struggling with this so much.

Comment: @bnr32jason: again, I've asked you to show these changes as an edit to your question -- but you've yet to do this. Please fix this so we can see what you're actually doing. Let's not get.

Comment: I'm trying to get something that is halfway coherent before I put in the edits, because as of right now, I'm completely confused and not making any sense with my changes in the code.

Comment: @bnr32jason: I'll wait.

Comment: I understand that you are trying to get me to do it on my own, and that's how I want to do it, but there are so many things I'm confused about which is why any of my code edits would be pointless. What exact code am I moving into the appendAutos method? All of the GUI constructor code? If so, then what do I do with the constructor? What parameters am I passing and where? Does the new appendAutos method need to return anything? I apologize for the trouble, but I am SERIOUSLY lost right now.  I've been trying different things for hours, and your comments are helpful, but I need more specifics.

Comment: Edited with what I have so far along with questions.

Comment: @bnr32jason Let me ask you this... Which section of code drawing the UI or draw what you want? Eel is telling you that the section of code that is drawing the UI needs to be repeatable. That's why he told you to create a separate method for it. Call it when the GUI is constructed and call it again when you want to wipe it and redraw it. Got the idea?

Comment: @pompanoSlayer I understand what I'm supposed to do, but I don't understand how to do it. The code we want repeated is currently in the constructor, but I can't call a constructor like a method. I try moving things out of the constructor into a new method, but I'm not sure how to format everything. I did a direct copy paste of the code, but I'm left with several errors that I don't know how to resolve. To start, how should I be formatting the method declaration? public void appendAutos(Automobile[] cars) ??

Comment: @bnr32jason Ask yourself this. What is needed for that method to do it magic? Does the method need to return anything back to the caller?

The way I see it public void appendAutos(Automobile[] cars) is a perfect start. I can see that part of your GUI code is missing. Seems like you have an array of cars in the GUI class?

Comment: @pompanoSlayer I'm not following you. My array object is instantiated and randomized in the Automobile.java class. In the GUI.java class that array is being sorted and placed into the JTextArea.

Comment: @pompanoSlayer I'm still confused as well as to why this isn't MUCH more simple. Why can't I just do the same thing as I did in the main method of the Automobile.java class, just without creating a new GUI window. Something is working, because when I do it that way and append the JTextArea it displays the array object information, but not the array itself. So I'm told to create an entirely new method and move all of my data around into that method, which is confusing me more. If someone showed me, I know that you are giving me the code, but you can see that I'm struggling greatly here. Thanks!

Comment: @pompanoSlayer I made it work, but not in the way suggested, I repeated all of the code right in the actionListener method instead of creating a new method. I'm still confused on how to pass the user entered integer into the suggested appendAutos method since it accepts an Array type variable.

Comment: @bnr32jason Here's how I would do it. My Automobile class would be just a POJO. There will not be a makeRadom method in it or public void main method in it. It just doesn't make sense for me that an Automobile class would be able to create instant of itself. I would have another class call AutomobileFactory and have the makeRadom method in it. I'll make another class that start up the program with public static void main method in that one. It'll call call AutomobileFactory to get an array of auto and then create a GUI class and then pass it the array. In the GUI class, I would call Auto

Comment: AutomobileFactory with the int that the user enter and then get the array and display it or add it to the original list. That is up to you. This way you won't have two method that does almost the same thing. That's why we are suggesting you to move that piece of code out of the GUI constructor.